# Add field in checkout prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I need some help with my checkout in prestashop 1.7
In the first step I want to delete "social title" and the box the says "får erbjudanden från våra partners" in English -> (Receive offers from our partners).
Se the attached picture step 1.

In the second step I want to change "Adresskomplement" in English -> (Address Complement) to Portkod (swedish) which means (gate access).
And also the other field to Övrigt or meddelande till Onlinesnacks. 
There is also a little box at the end of step 2 which I want to delete. 
Se the attached picture step 2.

and my last issue is in step 4. I want to delete the marked box on the picture step 4.

[STEP 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfL8A.png)

[STEP 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3YwK.png)

[STEP 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Kq1d.png)

Comment: here is step 4 https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Kq1d.png

Answer (score 3):

In order to remove Title, find and comment this block in /classes/form/CustomerFormatter.php

```
$genderField = (new FormField)
    ->setName('id_gender')
    ->setType('radio-buttons')
    ->setLabel(
        $this->translator->trans(
            'Social title', [], 'Shop.Forms.Labels'
        )
    )
;
foreach (Gender::getGenders($this->language->id) as $gender) {
    $genderField->addAvailableValue($gender->id, $gender->name);
}
$format[$genderField->getName()] = $genderField;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the hookDisplayBeforeCarrier() to render some JavaScript code to perform the actions you want.

This hook is rendered before the carrier block on the checkout page so it can be used to add some additional functionality on checkout page as well.

Comment: Thank you fpr your answer! But i bought help from somone in india at fiverr.com haha so the problem is now solved. but i'll still check your solutions because i still want to know the solution since me and my friends spent A LOT of time with this issue! Thanks!